# NoClassDefFoundError after upgrading to 1.7.0.RELEASE

Tags: playframework-2.3, spring-data-mongodb

I was trying to upgrade my application from 1.6.2.RELEASE to 1.7.0.RELEASE in my playframework project.
Insert queries are working fine but there seems to be an issue when spring-data tries to inflate the object using class name after fetching result against query, if there's no result against query then it returns an empty arraylist without throwing error.

1.7.0.RELEASE works fine in another project based on spring-integration framework.

below is statck trace :-

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/db/nosql/ACME
 models.db.nosql.ACME_Instantiator_gtblf6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 org.springframework.data.convert.BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:193)
 org.springframework.data.convert.BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:76)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:250)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:191)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2191)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1873)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1696)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1679)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:598)
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:589)
 GenerateACME.reverseBizCode(GenerateACME.java:42)
 Global.onStart(Global.java:23)
 play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:22)
 play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:220)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
 scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
 play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
 play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:157)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130)
 scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128)
 scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:120)
 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: What does `models/db/nosql/ACME` look like? Is that a Java or Scala class?

Comment: So, would you mind to show it? The crystal ball is so foggy otherwise…

Comment: I had the same trouble. After some searchs, I realised that could be a bug and I had to downgrade spring-data-mongodb to 1.6.2.RELEASE version.

Comment: any update on this issue, im also facing the same problem,

Comment: Try using morphia library that worked fine

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing this error too. I think it's the bug of the spring data mongodb.

If the Db model and all the service, repository are in one project, no such error. 
But if the service in another project, it can be reproduced 100%. I don't find a way to avoid this error.

Now, I'm trying to use the OGM on the mongodb persistent layer.

Comment: After long time investigation, the only way is that down to spring data mongodb 1.6.2 release. I doubt the self convert may be a workaround, but I don't try. And this bug isn't fixed on 1.8.x M1.