# NoClassDefFoundError when making a query in spring-data-solr within a play framework application

Tags: java, spring, solr, playframework, spring-data-solr

I keep running into an issue when making a spring-data-solr query from within my play framework v2.3.8 application. The query seems to succeed but then the class loader spring is using can't find the class files for my data model classes and throws a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Here is some relevant code.

First the data model in package 'model':

```
package model;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Theatre
{
    @Id
    String id;

    @Field
    String docType;

    // other fields, getters, and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Here is the repository:

```
package model;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.SolrCrudRepository;

public interface TheatreRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Theatre, String>
{
    List<Theatre> findByDocType(String doc__type);

    void delete(Theatre deleted);

    List<Theatre> findAll();

    Theatre findOne(String id);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Theatre save(Theatre persisted);
}
```

The Application class in play framework:

```
package controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import model.Theatre;
import model.TheatreRepository;

import play.*;

import plugins.solr.SolrPlugin;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {



    public static Result index() {

        TheatreRepository repository = Play.application().plugin( SolrPlugin.class ).getTheatreRepository();
        if( repository != null )
        {            
            List<Theatre> allTheatres = null;
            try
            {
                allTheatres = repository.findByDocType("theatre");
                Logger.info( "List of theatres found: " + allTheatres.toString() );
                for(Theatre theatre: allTheatres)
                {
                    Logger.info( "This theatre is: " + theatre.toString() );
                }
            }
            catch( NoClassDefFoundError | ClassNotFoundException e )
            {
                Logger.error( "Classpath: " + System.getProperty( "java.class.path" ) );
            }          
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.error( "TheatreRepository is NULL!" );
        }

        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }
}
```

And the ApplicationContext for spring:

```
package plugins.solr;

import play.Plugin;

import model.TheatreRepository;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import play.Logger;
import play.Play;
import play.api.Application;


public class SolrPlugin extends Plugin
{
    private TheatreRepository theatreRepository;    

    ApplicationContext ctx;

    public SolrPlugin(Application app)
    {

    }

    public TheatreRepository getTheatreRepository()
    {
        return theatreRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        Logger.info( "Solr plugin started" );

        ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SolrConfig.class);
        theatreRepository = ctx.getBean( TheatreRepository.class );
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaConfig based spring configuration:

```
package plugins.solr;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrOperations;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.EnableSolrRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.HttpSolrServerFactory;

import play.Play;

@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = { "model" })
public class SolrConfig
{
    public SolrConfig()
    {

    }

    @Bean
    public SolrServer solrServer()
    {
        HttpSolrServerFactory factory = new HttpSolrServerFactory( new HttpSolrServer( Play.application().configuration().getString( "ems.solr.url" ) ) );
        return factory.getSolrServer();
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrOperations solrTemplate()
    {
        return new SolrTemplate( this.solrServer() );
    }

}
```

So at run time `Application.index()` gets called when reloading the browser window and as a result the call to `theatreRepository.findByDocType("theatre");` gets executed. This is the stack trace from that call:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: model/Theatre
at model.Theatre_Instantiator_982rn.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:193) ~[spring-data-commons-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter.read(MappingSolrConverter.java:127) ~[spring-data-solr-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter.read(MappingSolrConverter.java:119) ~[spring-data-solr-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.Theatre
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:531) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at model.Theatre_Instantiator_982rn.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:193) ~[spring-data-commons-1.10.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

What I have noticed is that the `model.Theatre` class files are in play frameworks class loader but not in the system class loader. However, this doesn't seem like it should be a problem because spring was able to find the `TheatreRespoitory` class file when it needed to instantiate an instance of that class. I figure there must be something simple that I'm doing wrong but after trying a few things and doing research I'm still at a loss. 
I did find the following post but it doesn't seem to be relevant since it is referencing a difference between versions of spring-data-mongodb.

[MongoDB NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563481/noclassdeffounderror-after-upgrading-to-1-7-0-release)

Also, I just tried using the play frameworks class loader in the spring application context by doing the following in `SolrPlugin.onStart()`

```
ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SolrConfig.class);
((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext)ctx).setClassLoader( Play.application().classloader() );
```

This resulted in the same `NoClassDefFoundError` and stack trace. I also tried making the query in this same function, right after setting the class loader, and received the same error again.

Comment: I was never able to resolve this using spring-data-solr 1.4.0. However, I updated to spring-data-solr 1.4.1 and got past this error! So I guess this was a bug in 1.4.0. However, I found a bug in 1.4.1 as well. It seems that if you have any `multiValued` fields in your solr documents, spring-data-solr will fail with a null pointer exception in `MappingSolrConverter.SolrPropertyValueProvider.readValue()` when it tries to get the type attribute of the component via `type.getComponentType()`. I worked around this by removing all of the `multiValued` fields in my documents (not ideal)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to force `ReflectionEntityInstantiator` in `MappingMongoConverter` which reverts to pre 1.7.0.RELEASE instantiation strategy based on reflection. For example:

```
mappingConverter.setInstantiators(
    new EntityInstantiators(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.INSTANCE));
```

Comment: How will setting the instantiation strategy in `MappingMongoConverter` help me with the `mulitValued` fields in `MappingSolrConverter`?

Comment: This is a solution to `NoClassDefFoundError` caused by `BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator` as per stack trace. Notice the `Theatre_Instantiator_982rn` which is a runtime generated class. My solution changes from `BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator` to `ReflectionEntityInstantiator` which is slower but also doesn't depend as much on ClassLoader setup. More info here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/26/what-s-new-in-spring-data-fowler#performance-improvements-in-object-to-store-conversion.

Comment: Ok... but as I mentioned in my comment above this bug was fixed in 1.4.1 so there is no need to circumvent the `BytecodeGeneratingEntityInstantiator`. However, I may try your solution just to see if the `multiValued` solr field bug exists in 1.4.0 (my guess is that it does)